# Is the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q} \left(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}+i \right)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times\mathbb{Z}_{2} $?

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, abelian-groups

First of all, I proved that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}+i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7},i)$.Found that $|G|=|Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7},i)|=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7},i):\mathbb{Q}]=8$.
That's because $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7},i)$  is a splitting field of $f(x)=(x^2-5)(x^2-7)(x^2+1)/\mathbb{Q}$.Finally I showed that every $\sigma \in G $ has an order of 2 and that G is abelian.

Do the above really prove that $G \simeq Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2 ? $ 

Edit: here is a link on how i showed that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}+i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7},i)$ https://www.overleaf.com/read/bsrbxwnxnkcg

Comment: oops... i meant 1.Thank you for the point out

Comment: What have you computed for the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}+i$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I haven't yet , i really thought it wasn't necessary to be honest.I would probably use the formula $Irr(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}+i,\mathbb{Q})=\prod_{\sigma \in G}(x-\sigma(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}+i))$

Comment: Just taking the last sentence alone, the structure of finite abelian groups would say there is only one (the one you identify) isomorphism class of abelian groups of size 8 in which every element is its own inverse.

Comment: @irh Then my claim must be true (unless I miscalculated something) ,thank you .

Comment: How did you prove $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}+i) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7}, i)$?

Comment: @aschepler I showed that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7})$. Then with the same reasoning i showed that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}+i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7},i)$.I will edit the way.

Comment: @aschepler just did ,https://www.overleaf.com/read/bsrbxwnxnkcg

Comment: The minimal polynomial is $x^8-44x^6+542x^4+964x^2+841$, and it has Galois group $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$.

Comment: @this is the 1st time im hearing about this group to be honest. Does it behave like  $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ ?

Comment: @GrigorisKonstantopoylos It is the same group — because $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is often used for the $p$-adic integers, the group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is often written as $C_n$, the _cyclic_ group of order $n$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki did not know that! Thank you  very much!

Comment: Do you need an explicit argument to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}+i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}, i)$ implie that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}+i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7}, i)$? (Specifically, do you need to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7})$ implies that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}, i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7}, i)$?)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki i believe its really easy to recoginze that equality. However we could use the fact that every field mentioned is a splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}   (besides raw computations)